# How to record the call stack between two breakpoint?

Tags: python, debugging, logging, pycharm, breakpoints

I'm trying to using PyCharm to debug a large project. My problem is now I have the following code:

```py
objList = [obj1,obj2]
for obj in objList:
    fun(obj)
```

The expected result is that both of `fun(obj1)` and `fun(obj2)` will cause no error, but the fact is that `fun(obj2)` raise exception but `fun(obj1)` not. So I'd like to find the way to record the call stack of two function call and compare them to debug. Note that the `fun(obj1)` raise no error so breakpoint at exception will not be hit and project is large so it's infeasible to step into the function layer by layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires 2 steps, one for setting the breakpoint another for configuring the log file.

1.1. Right-click on the breakpoint and set a traceback function, in this example [`traceback.print_stack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_stack). (You will have to `import traceback` at the top of the module.)

[image: screenshot right-click on the breakpoint]

1.2. You can expand the dialogue by clicking "More".

[image: screenshot expanded right-click on the breakpoint]

2. Set the log file in `Run` `>` `Edit Configurations` `>` `Logs`

[image]