# PyCharm Debugger dies with "Windows fatal exception: access violation"

Tags: debugging, pycharm

### Short Description

I'm using PyCharm and am writing a pytest unit test.
I can run the test normally but if I try to debug it the debugger crashes.

> Windows fatal exception: access violation

### Stack Trace:

> Thread 0x00003588 (most recent call first):
> File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 324 in wait
> File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 600 in wait
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 150 in _on_run
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 218 in run
> File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009 in _bootstrap_inner
> File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 966 in _bootstrap

> Thread 0x000023f0 (most recent call first):
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 292 in _on_run
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 218 in run
> File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009 in _bootstrap_inner
> File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 966 in _bootstrap
> ...
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev_pydev_imps_pydev_execfile.py", line 18 in execfile
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1483 in _exec
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1476 in run
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2164 in main
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2173 in

> **Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)**

Comment: the problem is somewhat reproducible when adding a breakpoint at a raise statement

Comment: For me moving from python 3.10 to 3.9 solved the issue.

Comment: I'm having this same problem in python 3.9, but none of the solutions below work....

Answer (score 21):

Disabling all breakpoints fixed it for me:
[image]

Then I was able to set new ones.

Comment: other than suggested in the PyCharm BugTracker neither updating the IDE nor restarting nor  uninstallting various package versions fixed it for me.

Comment: You might want to delete all those breakpoints

Comment: I might. But they are there for a reason ;)

Comment: This has happened to me, PyCharm doesn't automatically delete breakpoints because they may contain complex information [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66954715), and [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66838346) the user may want to preserve as backup even if the module/project is long gone. It's strange that on occasion the IDE's debugger can still have some dependency on the outdated breakpoints (maybe to populate the GUI history) but yes it does happen and makes for an unexpected crash.

Comment: I still see this with Build #PY-221.5787.24, built on May 31, 2022 (Professional) with no solution yet. I confirm reinstalling Python and IDE did not help.

Comment: My observation is, that the error initially occurs if breakpoints are are set near/inside a codepath that may be "optimized" away, like close to an exception that is being raised, a continue or break statement. However the error does not go away if you remove only this single breakpoint. I do not have a MWE for that.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue with another error message. A type error , that only occurs in debugging a unittest but not when running it: "TypeError: unhashable type: 'cell'" can also be fixed by disabling all breakpoints.

Answer (score 2):

For me moving from python 3.10 to 3.9 solved the issue.

Comment: Me, too. There might be an error on Python 3.10 or some libraries.

Comment: can agree to that.

Comment: I catch it on Python 3.12

Answer (score 1):

Removing the breakpoints did not solve this for me. Moving from Python 3.10 to Python 3.11 did.

Comment: Did you check if e.g. rebuilding the virtual environment or creating a new one (and setting it as project interpreter via ctrl+alt+s)  also solves the issue?

Comment: Yes, it didn't.

Comment: I catch it on Python 3.12

Answer (score 0):

i had exactly the same issue,
what works for me right now , is to disable
"attach to subprocess automatically" in the pycharm debugger settings.

no idea why it works exactly...

Comment: Did not fix it for me.